# When navigating from one composable to another '+' is removed from string

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am navigating from one composable to another and I have a list of arguments one of which is a date string 2023-02-23T10:18:32.282+00:00, when sending this via compose arguments and fetching the same string with key dueDate, I am getting following output: 2023-02-23T10:18:32.282 00:00

This one does not contain a '+', is this a bug in jetpack compose?
here is my code:

```kotlin
navController.navigate(PosTempoRoute.LOAN_CONFIRMATION.getDestinationKey() +
"?supplierName=${supplierName}&dueDate=${dueDate}")
```

When receiving:

```kotlin
dueDateText = getString("dueDate") ?: "",
```

Comment: I know this is not relavent to your question, but you may want to check about "Compose Destinations" library, it was built around compose navigation. It provides easy Navigation and with type safety as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Uri.encode(yourString), when navigating using jetpack compose

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/270413904

Answer (score 0):

This is how we can send data from one composable function to another through compose navigation library like this

**First Screen**

You can send data through current backstack entry where you have to set key and value in navHostController instance.

```
val navHostController = rememberNavController()
    Button(onClick = {
        // passing data from one screen to another screen
        navHostController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set("key_name","value")
        navHostController.navigate("Second_Screen")
    }) {

    }
```

**Second Screen**

```
val value = navHostController.previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.get<String>("key_name") ?: ""
Text(text = value)
```

In this second screen , you can get data from previous backstack entry and also put null safety otherwise app will crash when you navigate back.